# Why is this prebuilt library complaining about undefined reference to functions that exist in the source code?

Tags: c, cmake, embedded, cypress

I have a rather large project that needed some porting to work on a PSoC6 device. I decided to go with the emFile library provided by cypress which can be found [here](https://github.com/Infineon/emfile)
I have no issues using the example emfile project in modustoolbox but when i try to compile it into my library im getting some strange errors from the linker when it tries to pull in the emfile library. I have had no issues so far porting other various parts of the project (i.e. gpio, spi, i2c, etc) but this is the first one that had an external library associated with it.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example_lib)

add_definitions(
    -DCOMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32
    -DCY8C624ABZI_S2D44
    -DCY_TARGET_DEVICE=CY8C624ABZI_S2D44
    -DTARGET_CY8CKIT_062S2_43012 
    -DCY_TARGET_BOARD=CY8CKIT_062S2_43012
    -DCOMPONENT_CAT1A
    -DCY_USING_HAL
    -DCOMPONENT_RTOS_AWARE
    -DCOMPONENT_HARDFP
    -DCOMPONENT_CM4
    -DCOMPONENT_MURATA_1LV 
    -DCOMPONENT_PSOC6HAL
)
  
add_library(example_lib STATIC  
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/TARGET_CY8CKIT-062S2-43012/release-v3.0.0/COMPONENT_CM4/system_psoc6_cm4.c
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/Config/FS_ConfigMMC_CM_HS.c
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/Driver/MMC_CM/FS_MMC_HW_CM.c
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/OS/FS_OS_MTBAbsRTOS.c
    src/example.c
)

target_include_directories(example_lib PUBLIC
    inc
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/core-lib/release-v1.3.0/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/Driver/MMC_CM
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/core-lib/release-v1.3.0/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/TARGET_CY8CKIT-062S2-43012/release-v2.3.0
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-hal-cat1/release-v2.0.1/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-hal-cat1/release-v2.0.1/COMPONENT_PSOC6HAL/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-hal-cat1/release-v2.0.1/COMPONENT_PSOC6HAL/COMPONENT_CAT1A/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-pdl-cat1/release-v2.3.1/devices/COMPONENT_CAT1A/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-pdl-cat1/release-v2.3.1/cmsis/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/mtb-pdl-cat1/release-v2.3.1/drivers/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/abstraction-rtos/release-v1.5.0/include
    ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/abstraction-rtos/release-v1.5.0/include/COMPONENT_FREERTOS
)

link_directories(${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM)
target_link_libraries(prcv-os ${CMAKE_CYPRES_LIBRARIES}/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a)
```

and here is the output i get when i try to compile it:

```
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_Misc.o):C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_Misc.c:85: undefined reference to `FS_X_GetTimeDate'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_LockDriver':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:249: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Lock'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_UnlockDriver':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:266: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Unlock'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Lock':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:286: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Lock'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Unlock':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:297: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Unlock'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Init':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:313: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Init'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_DeInit':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:330: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_DeInit'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_GetTime':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:390: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_GetTime'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Delay':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:416: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Delay'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Wait':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:454: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Wait'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_OS_Interface.o): in function `FS_OS_Signal':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_OS_Interface.c:477: undefined reference to `FS_X_OS_Signal'
~/ModusToolbox/tools_2.4/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ~/mtw/mtb_shared/emfile/release-v1.0.0/FS/COMPONENT_EMFILE_FAT32/COMPONENT_CM4/COMPONENT_HARDFP/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a(FS_Core.o): in function `FS_STORAGE_Init':
C:\wspace\GitLab\emfile\source\build_libs/emFile_PRO_Src_V5.6.1_FS/FS/FS_Core.c:587: undefined reference to `FS_X_AddDevices'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:282: CMakeFiles/example] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
build.sh: build failed!
```

it looks like something in the library is referencing functions defined in the emfile source code where the configuration is:

```
emfile/Config/FS_ConfigMMC_CM_HS.c
```

Im insanely lost on this, i hope this is just some simple flag or something i am missing in the cmake file.

Comment: It would help if you posted the `ld` command that is failing. I think all of the FS_OS_* (I didn't check them all) symbols are provided by libemfile_fat32_cm4f_gcc.a. Maybe the lib/objects are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Richard i believe i did post all of the ld commands that failed. they are all pointing to undefined references to FS_X_OS_* functions

Comment: You did post the output. But I need to see the command that was run to know what `ld` thinks you've asked it to do.

Comment: Im a little confused on exactly what you want. i provided my CMakeLists.txt file i used to build it and to build it i just run the cmake build. i can provide you my toolchain cross compiler if thats what you want. Otherwise, i call target_link_libraries in my CMakeLists file which i believe would be the ld command

Comment: Running `make VERBOSE=1` will print the commands it's running as well as the standard cmake pretty print. It would help to see the command it ran just before the errors.